# How to add behavior via JavaScript on infinite scroll results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've developed a search page with infinite scroll (using jQuery, no plug-ins) and now I wonder how can I add some behavior to the HTML I get back from the WS I call. I need to add some JavaScript via jQuery selectors, but I've always relied on the

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

so far, that doesn't trigger when I append HTML code to may page. The only idea I had is to inject the JS code after the jQuery AJAX call in case of SUCCESS event

```
function injectJS(){
   $('.elementA').click(function(){ /* do something */ });
   $('.elementB').click(function(){ /* do something */ });
   ...
   $('.elementZ').click(function(){ /* do something */ });
}

$.ajax({
   url: "/ajax/v1/path",
   type: "post",
   data: data, 
   success: function (data) {
      // 1. Add HTML to the page
      // 2. Inject JS to DOM objects
      injectJS
   },
   error: function (e) {
      console.log('error:'+e);
   }
});
```

Is this the only solution?

I have to say this approach appear rather bad to me because It will inject the code to all the matching elements in the page, even those previously fetched.

Comment: Remind me not to search on your site then... http://xkcd.com/1309/

Comment: Learn about `event delegation` - http://api.jquery.com/on/ / http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
function injectJS(){
   $(document).on('click', '.elementA', function(){ /* do something */ });
   // ...
}
```

Long answer:

Look up

- "JavaScript event bubbling" and/or
- "JavaScript event delegation"
- [jQuery's documentation on `on()`.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)